# output .csv file only writing last query. How do I get it to print all url checks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

input.csv has a list of urls in one column to check. It runs these checks perfectly and then the script is supposed to write out which sites are up and which are down. However, the last part of the code only seems to write the last site checked. How can I get it to write all checks to the output.csv?

```
import re
import requests
from itertools import product, cycle
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen


with open("input.csv") as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        s = 'Quantity' or 'Stock'
        r = requests.get(row[0])
        result = re.search(s, r.text)
        if result == None:
            print("OUT OF STOCK")
            inis = "OUT OF STOCK"
        else:
            print("In Stock")
            inis = "In Stock"

        new_column = [(row[0]) + " " + inis]
        print(row[0])


with open("output.csv", "w") as f:
    for col in new_column:
        f.write(col + "\n")
```

Comment: check how you assign to `new_column`. It overwrites itself `for row in csv.reader(f):...`

Comment: I tried pulling from row alone but that didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the script is supposed to write out which sites are up and which are down

I'm not sure where the 'stock' terminology comes from, but assuming the logic code is correct, why not try something like this...

Create an empty list first, then on each iteration of the loop append a row to it:

```
with open("input.csv") as f:
    new_column = []
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        s = 'Quantity' or 'Stock'
        r = requests.get(row[0])
        result = re.search(s, r.text)
        if result == None:
            inis = "OUT OF STOCK"
        else:
            inis = "In Stock"

        new_column.append(f"{row[0]},{inis}")

        print(row[0], inis)
```

`new_column` is now a list of CSV compatible rows, which can be written to `output.csv` with your exisiting code.

Comment: You got it! Thank you!